# Copy values from json string to javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The angular extend https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

copies all properties from source to target. This is not what I want because my target is already created I just need to copy all values from json string to the target javascript object.

Those values who shall copied have the same property names in source and target object.

Does there exist any angularJS or javascript predefined function to do this job?

Comment: Extend should still work for this. If you have a JSON string, you can do `angular.extend(my_obj, JSON.parse(json_string))`

Comment: @Brennan Does Extend not copy properties? The thread opener wants to copy values not properties so I understood?!

Comment: @Brennan .extend does not copy values it copies the properties with its values. This is not what I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have created my own AutoMapper as I could not find something usable in google:

Pass a source and target object to the transform function and from every source object properties which can be found on the target the values are copied :-)

```
'use strict';
angular.module('mymodule').service('AutoMapper', function () {

    this.transform = function (source, target) {
        for (var sourceProperty in source) {
            for(var targetProperty in target)
            {
                if(targetProperty === sourceProperty)
                {
                    target[targetProperty] = source[sourceProperty];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of angular.copy [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) on the same

Working code:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
<form novalidate class="simple-form">
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
E-mail: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br />
Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
<input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female<br />
<button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
<button ng-click="update(user)">SAVE</button>
</form>
<pre>form = {{user | json}}</pre>
<pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
</div>

<script>
 angular.module('copyExample', [])
   .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.master= {};

     $scope.update = function(user) {
       // Example with 1 argument
       $scope.master= angular.copy(user);
     };

     $scope.reset = function() {
       // Example with 2 arguments
       angular.copy($scope.master, $scope.user);
     };

     $scope.reset();
   }]);
</script>
```